# Port redirection from interface with mirror port traffic (iptables)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have an openSUSE linux server running Suricata as IDS. The server has two interfaces. The first one (eth0) is for pure administration like ssh. The second interface (eth5) has no IP set and gets the complete traffic of a datacenter via mirror port of a switch connected there.
So far everything works as it should.

```
testsystem:/home/admin # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:23:52:a5:26:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno1
    altname enp1s0f0
    inet6 fe80::8218:44ff:fee2:9424/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:23:52:a5:26:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno2
    altname enp1s0f1
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:23:52:a5:26:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno3
    altname enp2s0f0
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:23:52:a5:26:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno4
    altname enp2s0f1
6: eth4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a5:33:d4:c7:21:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
7: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a5:33:d4:c7:21:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f1
    inet6 fe80::a2d3:c1ff:fec6:e29c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vlan20@eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a5:33:d4:c7:21:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: vlan30@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:23:52:a5:26:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.20.40/24 brd 10.1.20.255 scope global vlan30
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8218:44ff:fee2:9424/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now I want to use sslsplit to split the incoming traffic to a web server. Since we have the server key for the web server, this should not be a problem. Outgoing traffic will still be encrypted.
On port 8443 sslsplit is now listening and waiting for the (still) encrypted network packets.

I am now trying to redirect the packets to the web server (12.34.56.78) and port 443 to the service running on localhost on port 8443 using iptables on eth5. I have tried a redirect as well as DNAT in the prerouting chain. Unfortunately no packets are passing through the rules there, although the packets can be seen using tcpdump.

```
testsystem:/home/admin # iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 12.34.56.78 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8443

testsystem:/home/admin # iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 39388 packets, 7552K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 65264 packets, 204M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

testsystem:/home/admin # iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 325 packets, 26961 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            12.34.56.78          tcp dpt:443 to:127.0.0.1:8443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 408 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 147 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 147 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

```
testsystem:/home/admin # tcpdump -i eth5 -n host 12.34.56.78 and port 443
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:50:57.253814 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [S], seq 3314657542, win 62727, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 24135814 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:50:57.253995 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [S.], seq 20818400, ack 3314657543, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1082431744 ecr 24135814,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:50:57.355763 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 491, options [nop,nop,TS val 24135916 ecr 1082431744], length 0
11:50:57.358522 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 491, options [nop,nop,TS val 24135919 ecr 1082431744], length 517
11:50:57.358667 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 0
11:50:57.359046 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359058 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 1449:2897, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359074 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [P.], seq 2897:4097, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1200
11:50:57.359079 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 4097:5545, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359090 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 5545:6993, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359103 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 6993:8441, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359118 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [.], seq 8441:9889, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 1448
11:50:57.359120 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [P.], seq 9889:10061, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431770 ecr 24135919], length 172
11:50:57.373545 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [P.], seq 10061:10664, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431773 ecr 24135919], length 603
11:50:57.460834 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 2897, win 469, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136022 ecr 1082431770], length 0
11:50:57.460853 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 4097, win 460, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136022 ecr 1082431770], length 0
11:50:57.460861 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 6993, win 438, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136022 ecr 1082431770], length 0
11:50:57.460875 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 10061, win 415, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136022 ecr 1082431770], length 0
11:50:57.475328 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 10664, win 443, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136036 ecr 1082431773], length 0
11:50:57.558250 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [P.], seq 518:644, ack 10664, win 443, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136119 ecr 1082431773], length 126
11:50:57.558868 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [P.], seq 10664:10938, ack 644, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431820 ecr 24136119], length 274
11:50:57.660641 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 10938, win 443, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136221 ecr 1082431820], length 0
11:50:57.680227 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [P.], seq 644:829, ack 10938, win 443, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136241 ecr 1082431820], length 185
11:50:57.680435 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42260: Flags [P.], seq 10938:11502, ack 829, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 1082431850 ecr 24136241], length 564
11:50:57.782216 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42260 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [.], ack 11502, win 443, options [nop,nop,TS val 24136343 ecr 1082431850], length 0
11:50:57.986870 IP xx.xx.xx.xx.42396 > 12.34.56.78.443: Flags [S], seq 502575886, win 62727, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 24136548 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:50:57.987011 IP 12.34.56.78.443 > xx.xx.xx.xx.42396: Flags [S.], seq 2750760101, ack 502575887, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1082431927 ecr 24136548,nop,wscale 7], length 0
^C
27 packets captured
355 packets received by filter
210 packets dropped by kernel
```

It looks to me like the prerouting chain is being ignored as the total counter of the packets is also way too low.
Does anyone have an idea and can help further?

Comment: During tcpdump, the interface is put in promiscuous mode. Does tcpdump still capture something when also using the `-p` option?. Anyway this question's goal appear to be flawed in multiple ways: you can't get it working with an application listening on tcp port 8443: it's mirrored traffic, not routed traffic so the tcp stack can't be involved (it would require actively answering). Then doing a redirection to 127.0.0.1 will later cause a routing issue.

Comment: With ```-p```, tcpdump can no longer see packets.
The traffic is only a copy and should only be forwarded once to port 8443, after that it is discarded. Finally only the copy should be analyzed, while the original traffic passes the mirror port normally. Do you think this is not possible?

Comment: This would be possible for receiving UDP, not receiving TCP: TCP requires ACKs to be sent back by the (OS on behalf of the) application listening on the TCP port. I can imagine suricata should have other modes of usage adapted to analyzing mirrored traffic, probably working like tcpdump: using capture.

Comment: And even for receiving UDP by an application working with an UDP socket, tweaks would have to be used anyway, probably lowering suricata's ability to analyze: the incoming frame's destination Ethernet MAC address has to be changed to eth5's MAC address or the network stack will probably drop the packet (as it probably did here even if in promiscuous mode).

Comment: The interface on the mirror port handles the incoming as well as the outgoing traffic (this info may still be missing). The interface is not supposed to and technically can't send packets. It is only supposed to put the encrypted packets together if necessary and break them open for analysis. There are extra professional tools that can do that. But you have already given me a good hint in the probably right direction with the hint to promiscuous mode. Thanks!